# How to make mail notification/alert

Tags: spring, monitoring, tcserver, spring-insight

I'm using Spring-Insight and Pivotal tc server to deploy and monitor two Spring applications but I have to create some alerts in case of threshold violation. Do you know if this is possible to make this alerting system without creating a customized plugin? I just can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I didn't find any solution to my problem but I think this is possible with a customized plugin. I personally chose another option : monitor my application with Dynatrace even if Dynatrace isn't free.